# Photo-multiplier Tube Pin Configuration

Tags: optoelectronics, vacuum-tube, photosensor, tube

Pin configuration of a photo-multiplier tube (PMT) is presented in its manual as can be seen in the attached image. All dynodes have been related to specified pins (numbered circles in the image) except Photo-cathode and Modulator that they are marked with the letters "Phi" and "M" respectively.

[image]

This PMT is manufactured by GS-Tube (https://www.gstube.com) and its part number is FEU-49B. The image below shows a view of the PMT. Now, I don't know how these pins can be connect to high voltage power supply when there is no identified pin?

[image]

Comment: You will be working with dangerous voltages. Are you ok with this issue?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the device? The *phi, M* connections may be on the body or any other exposed metallic part. Also, what are 17, 18 and 19 connected to ?

Comment: What model number of PMT is that? Ex-Soviet?

Comment: _" it is unknown that how Photo-cathode and Modulator can be biased by proper voltage level?"_ - what does the datasheet say?

Comment: I'm so sorry about delay in answer. I edit my question so the model and picture of PMT is presented. due to datasheet pins 17, 18, 19 have the same potential as modulator pin but there is no explanation about permission to apply voltage to these pins.

Answer (score 4):

[GS Tube](https://www.gstube.com) doesn't make the FEU49B, or any other tube.  They sell new old stock Soviet produced vacuum tubes.

The datasheets are therefore difficult to read - I know English and German, but no Russian.

As I understand your question, you are looking for the pins for "Photo cathode" and "Modulator," and can't find them on the pins that go into the socket.

They aren't there.

They are on the tube itself.

[image]

That picture from the [GS Tubes FEU49B page](https://www.gstube.com/data/3088/) shows the K (cathode) to the far left of the schematic representation of the tube.  The drawing of the tube to the right shows the K connection on the side of the tube.  (At the bottom of the drawing of the tube.)

Your other missing pin is then the one marked "Y9" (the concentric circles) drawn on the tube.

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone from Anthony Izaguirre please go to GS tube.com open FEU-49 file and use the lower schematic (B) showing 15 resistors and 3 capacitors the values for R1,R2 and R3 is 20 megohms resistors R4 thru R15 are all 10 megohms operating voltage is 1250 volts DC. on the side of the tube the side electrode closest to the face of the tube is the photocathode (K) the second side electrode is the first focus element electrode the second focus element is pin 16 on the tube socket the schematic shows 2 focus elements and 12 dynodes 1 photocathode and one anode R15 is connected to the anode.Do not solder to the PMT pins directly.Remove the pins from old 7 or 9 pin tube sockets carefully you need 20 socket pins solder your resistors to these new pins that you just added. Note not all are used- pins 15,17,18,19 and 20 are not used they were added in to strengthen the home made socket.Please draw the socket out first so you know where the wires and resistors go to. This is a time consuming project and requires great attention and skill I will take pictures of a working FEU-49 PMT Scintillator and include them soon. The hardest part is making a 20 pin tube socket. Mine is made from FR-4 pc board or G-10 glass pc board then add your wires making it a flying wire tube socket. use the PMT tube to locate the pins in their proper locations and solder the old tube 7 or 9 pins you removed earlier to the pc board that you made it's not super hard but very time consuming then solder in your resistors from the drawing you made as to their locations. I spent 2 days making the socket etch and drill you will be very happy and well rewarded when your device works I will add pictures soon I hope this helps

Comment: An image or a link to the schematic would be useful. Please [edit] your answer and provide.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone from Anthony Izaguirre  Pin 1 is the short pin  Pin 2 is the first long pin to the left of the short pin which pin #1  the photocathode is the first recessed pin on the side of the tube closest to the front face the second recessed pin is the first focus element the second focus element is pin 16 when looking at the bottom schematic(GStube.com) resistors R1,R2,R3 are 20 Megohm resistorsR4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 are all 10 Megohm 1/4 watt metal film, R15 is connected to the anode. operating voltage is 1250 volts   This is a very sensitive tube. I am using Bicron BC-412 plastic scintillator 7 inch by 7 inch by 2.25 inch thick with silicon coupling grease I made the socket for this tube using the pins removed from 9 pin tube sockets   do not solder the pins on PMT this is a very impressive tube I hope this helps everyone that has this tube wanting to put it into service Best wishes

Comment: Anthony Izaguirre - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However it is very difficult to understand your answer :( (a) More punctuation & blank space would help, as we can't see where you intend each sentence to start & stop. (Formatting help is [here](/help/formatting).) (b) You mention many resistors, but the schematics in the question and the other answer don't show any. Are you looking at [this gstube.com page](https://www.gstube.com/data/3088/)? (c) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. || Please can you [edit] your answer to clarify?